# Julia: read("count_heads.jl", String) conversion error

Tags: type-conversion, julia

I am going through [Parallel Loops and Maps](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/parallel-computing#Parallel-Map-and-Loops-1) and I am seeming to have difficulty with even accessing the file `count_heads.jl`

I saved it in my working directory

```
function count_heads(n)
    c::Int = 0
    for i = 1:n
        c += rand(Bool)
    end
    c
end
```

And I can verify it's existence in that directory:

```
filter(r"count_heads.jl", readdir())
#1-element Array{String,1}:
#"count_heads.jl"
```

Yet when I attempt the next step in the tutorial.

```
@everywhere include_string(Main, $(read("count_heads.jl", String)), "count_heads.jl")
ERROR: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Type{String} to an object of type Array{UInt8,1}
This may have arisen from a call to the constructor Array{UInt8,1}(...),
since type constructors fall back to convert methods.
```

Looking at just the `read("count_heads.jl", String)` function I get the source of the error (I think).

Comment: The code works on my system (julia 0.6 on Mac, testing in Juno)

Comment: Just `read("count_heads.jl", String)` gives me `"function count_heads(n)\n    c::Int = 0\n    for i = 1:n\n        c += rand(Bool)\n    end\n    c\nend\n"`

Comment: I was afraid of that. These kind of idiosyncratic errors are really hard to nail down.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using an older version of Julia (Julia 0.5?).  read(filename, String) requires Julia 0.6 or later (https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/22793).

Comment: Wish it were the case `Version 0.6.0 (2017-06-19 13:05 UTC)`

Comment: `readstring` was deprecated to `read(io, String)`, but that PR (https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/22864) didn't make into v0.6. On v0.6 or earlier, you can use `readstring` or `using Compat` to use the new syntax `read(filename, String)`